How to check a kworker workqueue
after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04 I noticed that the performance of my SSD has decreased when testing fio workloads.
Comparing both versions with perf record I noticed a kworker in 22.04 that is running significantly that wasn't in 18.04: Kworker/u64:3-f. I understand the naming process for kworkers but I'm not sure how I can find out what the workqueue name is for this kworker so that I can look at the event in more depth, how can I get the full workqueue name?
